# Bootstrap navbar hamburger menu - 2 column table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap navbarsetup with 3 options and then a dropdown menu. This all works very well on my browser (code below)

What I would like to do is change the menu so that when the hamburger icon becomes visible, the menu is presented in a two column table with ALL items (main and dropdown) displayed rather than the 3 options and a "More..." item

Is this possible through bootstrap/CSS or will I effectively have to build two menus?

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-left" href="/home/"><span class="logo"></span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="">
          <a href="/opt1/">Option 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/opt2/">Option 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="/opt3/">Option 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More...<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="">
              <a href="/drop1/">Dropdown 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/drop2r/">Dropdown 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/drop3/">Dropdown 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="/drop4/">Dropdown 4</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by two-column table? Can you elaborate or show a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://www.bootply.com/twaM4o0sej

You need to override the styles that cause it to open on click, and instead have it open on default. I also had to hide the link that says "more" for mobile so it doesn't show up. Just adjust the padding and you're good.

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    .dropdown-menu{
        display: block;
        position: static;
        background-color:transparent;
        border:0 none;
        box-shadow:none;
        margin-top:0;
        position:static;
        width:100%;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More...<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="/drop1/">Dropdown 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="/drop2r/">Dropdown 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="/drop3/">Dropdown 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="/drop4/">Dropdown 4</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
```